# lookuporderedrows with additional IF condition

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using LookupOrderedRows on the **Quote_E_data** using the **Id** column to match.

When there is a match it displays the values **Daily_Charge__c** & **Variable_1__c** in a table format.

In this DE if there are multiple rows and the **Id_Product** value is different then it displays another table with the above stated values.

`IF Field(Row(@cRows, @i), "Id_product") != @Id_product THEN` This part works fine.

What i want to do is ADD another IF condition to this e.g.

`IF Field(Row(@cRows, @i), "Id_product") != @Id_product AND Field(Row(@cRows, @i), "E-meters") == "1" THEN`

This is not working and the error says **IF statement not closed with ENDIF.**

I have tried putting the ENDIF in different places but it corrupts the rest of the code.

How should i alter the existing code (below) to achieve this.

```
SET @cid = AttributeValue("Id")
SET @cRows = LookupOrderedRows("Quote_E_data", 0, "Id_product, E_meters, Daily_Charge__c, Variable_1__c ", "Id", @cid)

IF RowCount(@cRows) > 0 THEN
  FOR @i = 1 TO RowCount(@cRows) DO
    IF Field(Row(@cRows, @i), "Id_product") != @Id_product THEN
      IF @i > 1 THEN
]%%
%%[ENDIF]%%

<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Charge type</td>
    <td>Price (excl. GST)</td>
  </tr>
  %%[

ENDIF
    SET @E_meters = Field(Row(@cRows, @i), "E_meters ")
    SET @Daily_Charge__c = Field(Row(@cRows, @i), "Daily_Charge__c")
    SET @Variable_1__c = Field(Row(@cRows, @i), "Variable_1__c")    
    
]%%

  <tr>
    <td>Daily Charge - c/day </td>
    <td>%%=v(@Daily_Charge__c)=%%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Variable</td>
    <td>%%=v(@Variable_1__c)=%%</td>
  </tr>

  %%[
  NEXT
  ELSE
]%%
     %%[ENDIF]%%
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your case correctly, I think you just need to keep track of the previous product and check when it changes.  Here's how I'd approach it:

```ampscript
%%[

set @debug = 1
set @cid = attributevalue("id")
set @rows = lookuporderedrows("Quote_E_data", 0, "id_product, e_meters, daily_charge__c, variable_1__c ", "id", @cid)
set @rowcount = rowcount(@rows)
set @prev_id_product = ""

if @debug == 1 then 
 output(concat("<br>rowcount: ", @rowcount))
endif

if @rowcount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowcount do

    set @row = row(@rows, @i)
    set @id_product = field(@row, "id_product")
    set @e_meters = field(@row, "e_meters")
    set @daily_charge__c = field(@row, "daily_charge__c")
    set @variable_1__c = field(@row, "variable_1__c")

    /* start a new table on first or when product changes */
    if @id_product != @prev_id_product then
      ]%%
         <table border='1'>
           <tr>
             <td>charge type</td>
             <td>price (excl. gst)</td>
           </tr>
      %%[
    endif 
    ]%%

    <tr>
      <td>daily charge - c/day</td>
      <td>%%=v(@daily_charge__c)=%%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>variable</td>
      <td>%%=v(@variable_1__c)=%%</td>
    </tr>

    %%[ 

    if @id_product != @prev_id_product or @i == @rowcount then 

      set @prev_id_product = @id_product 

      ]%%

      </table>

      %%[

    endif /* end of product or last row */

  next @i

endif /* rowcount check */

]%%
```

You've also got an extraneous space after `E_meters` in this line:

```
SET @E_meters = Field(Row(@cRows, @i), "E_meters ")
```

Test: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/oVPA8DQE

Comment: This code will sit in an email content block which will be dynamically used when E_meters = 1
There could be two other possibilities where E_meters could be 2 or 3 where an extra <tr> is added respectively.

I didn’t think there was a way to display a table with conditional <tr> tags so I went with the separate email content blocks approach.